# Rally Changeset request returning null

Tags: spring, get, automation, rally, changeset

I am attempting to automate some stuff in my Rally environment. Just as of a few days ago I have having this problem that I cannot seem to fix when I attempt to a valid rest exchange with Rally for information about some Changesets. This is run using Tomcat and simply listens from another server we have.

Here is some of the code and some logs:

```
String changesetRef defect.getAsJsonObject().get("Changesets").getAsJsonObject().get("_ref")
                    .toString();
            try {
                ResponseEntity<QueryResultWrapper> changeSetsRequest = caller.callRestfulAPIForRally(
                        changesetRef.substring(1, changesetRef.length() - 1), httpmethod,
                        new ParameterizedTypeReference<QueryResultWrapper>() {
                        });


// The Auth key is received from a file

public <T> ResponseEntity<T> callRestfulAPIForRally(String url, HttpMethod method, ParameterizedTypeReference<T> paramRef) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Authorization", RallyAuthKey);
    headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    headers.add("Accepts", "application/json");
    return callRestfulAPI(url, headers, method, paramRef);
}


private <T> ResponseEntity<T> callRestfulAPI(String url, HttpHeaders headers, HttpMethod method, ParameterizedTypeReference<T> paramRef) {

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory simpleFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();

    //Set timeout on connection to 20 seconds
    simpleFactory.setConnectTimeout(20*1000);

    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(simpleFactory));
    ResponseEntity<T> result = restTemplate.exchange(url, method, new HttpEntity<String>(headers), paramRef);
    logger.info("Result: " + result.toString());
    logger.info("Result body: " + result.getBody());
    return result;
}
```

These loggers return the following when this is run:

```
INFO - Result: <200 

OK,com.mycompany.webservice.core.jenkins.QueryResultWrapper@33eb30ec,{Date=[Thu, 07 Jul 2016 22:08:41 GMT], Content-Type=[application/json;  charset=utf-8], Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], Connection=[keep-alive], Set-Cookie=[__cfduid=dc0b3ebf63634c86250efdedf10fd4ead1467929321; expires=Fri, 07-Jul-17 22:08:41 GMT; path=/; domain=.rallydev.com; HttpOnly, JSESSIONID=qs-app-111wgnt86c424tz1hwu48m187shg.qs-app-11;Path=/;Secure;HttpOnly, ZSESSIONID=CONFIDENTIAL;Path=/;Domain=rally1.rallydev.com;Secure;HttpOnly, SUBBUCKETID=0;Path=/;Domain=rally1.rallydev.com;Secure;HttpOnly, SERVERID=CONFIDENTIAL; path=/], Strict-Transport-Security=[max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains], X-XSS-Protection=[1; mode=block], RallyRequestID=[qs-app-111wgnt86c424tz1hwu48m187shg.qs-app-1128098501], Expires=[Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT], ETag=[W/"028b6add6cf4389520d5bdb5163a9a21c"], Vary=[Accept-Encoding], P3P=[CP="NON DSP COR CURa PSAa PSDa OUR NOR BUS PUR COM NAV STA"], Cache-Control=[private,max-age=0,must-revalidate], Server=[cloudflare-nginx], CF-RAY=[2bee9dd3697809b2-ORD]}>
    2016-07-07 17:08:41,361 RestCallHelper                       
    INFO - Result body:com.mycompany.webservice.core.jenkins.QueryResultWrapper@33eb30ec
```

Here is the structure for the request and how I have it set up... Spring should autopopulate all of theses values.

```
QueryResultWrapper
 --> QueryResult
    --> Results[]
       --> Changes
          -->_ref
```

When this executes it says it has made a GET request that, when I copy and past it into the browser, contains a valid Json like this:

```
{"QueryResult": {"_rallyAPIMajor": "2", "_rallyAPIMinor": "0", "Errors": [], "Warnings": [], "TotalResultCount": 1, "StartIndex": 1, "PageSize": 20, "Results": [{"_rallyAPIMajor": "2", "_rallyAPIMinor": "0", "_ref": "STUFF IS IN HERE", "_refObjectUUID": "9b96f131-f7a3-4615-b699-f793677836ba", "_objectVersion": "2", "_refObjectName": "Automate-web:057c595a52d0b39233bc4796d69cb09fb329d007", "CreationDate": "2016-07-07T18:45:31.240Z", "_CreatedAt": "today at 1:45 pm", "ObjectID": 58917491560, "ObjectUUID": "9b96f131-f7a3-4615-b699-f793677836ba", "VersionId": "2", "Subscription": {STUFF IS IN HERE}, "Workspace": {STUFF IS IN HERE }, "Artifacts": {STUFF IS IN HERE}, "Author": {STUFF IS IN HERE}, "Branch": null, "Builds": {STUFF IS IN HERE}, "Changes": {STUFF IS IN HERE}, "CommitTimestamp": "2016-07-07T18:44:16.000Z", "Message": "DE3333.  Check for an agent on the agent lookup.", "Name": "CONFIDENTIAL", "Revision": "057c595a52d0b39233bc4796d69cb09fb329d007", "SCMRepository": {STUFF IS IN HERE}, "Uri": "STUFF IS IN HERE", "_type": "Changeset"}]}}
```

Now why does `QueryResult` return `null`?

Answer (score 1):

It happens that the Spring integration of Jackson doesn't seem to like how the QueryResultWrapper looks and was not able to assign that variable anything. This is the following changes I made to no use Jackson.

```
public <T> T callRestfulAPIForRallyObjectMapper(String url, HttpMethod method, T obj) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Authorization", RallyAuthKey);
    headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    headers.add("Accepts", "application/json");
    return callRestfulAPIObjectMapper(url, headers, method, obj);
}    
private <T> T callRestfulAPIObjectMapper(String url, HttpHeaders headers, HttpMethod method, T obj) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory simpleFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();

        //Set timeout on connection to 20 seconds
        simpleFactory.setConnectTimeout(20*1000);

        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(simpleFactory));
        ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(url, method, new HttpEntity<String>(headers), new ParameterizedTypeReference<String>(){});

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T wrapper = (T) mapper.readValue(result.getBody(), obj.getClass());

        return wrapper;
    }
```

This is the changes I made in the code that calls the methods.

```
  QueryResultWrapper changeSetsRequest = caller.callRestfulAPIForRallyObjectMapper(
                            changesetRef.substring(1, changesetRef.length() - 1), httpmethod,
                            new QueryResultWrapper());
                    QueryResult qr = changeSetsRequest.getQueryResult();
```